# Bert Tokenizer is not working despite importing all packages. Is there a new syntax change to this?

Tags: python, tokenize, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

Trying to run the tokenizer for Bert but I keep getting errors. Can anyone help where I am going wrong.

```
FullTokenizer = bert.bert_tokenization.FullTokenizer
bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1", trainable=False)
vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy()
do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case)
```

Error: AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () ----> 1 FullTokenizer = bert.bert_tokenization.FullTokenizer 2 bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1", 3 trainable=False) 4 vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy() 5 do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()

AttributeError: module 'bert' has no attribute 'bert_tokenization'

All the below have been imported for reference.

```
!pip install bert-for-tf2
!pip install sentencepiece
!pip install bert-tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==2.0

try:
    %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
    pass
import tensorflow as to
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import bert
from bert import tokenization
```

Answer (score 2):

I was caught up in a similar situation before.

Try looking for a folder named "bert" in the directory where your script/notebook is being run. Delete that folder or rename it to something other than "bert". There is a very likely possibility that when you import bert, it tries to access that folder intead of the bert-for-tf2 which you installed in the Python site packages.

If still that doesn't work, try

from bert import tokenization

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install bert-tensorflow
!pip install --upgrade bert
!pip install tokenization

from bert import tokenization
from bert.tokenization.bert_tokenization import FullTokenizer
tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. While you probably had a valid idea while writing this answer it would have beend great if you would have explained it here. It looks like most of the commands you posted are already in the question, so It is highly unclear why your code would solve the underlying issue